# Is it possible join two modules as top-level in GHCI?

Tags: haskell

I discovered that changing order or paths given to `:load` changes visible bindings and it seems impossible to debug multiple modules at the same time. It is especially annoying as I lose bindings every time I `:load`.

It seems there can be only one module in [`*-form`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-scope) as suggested by wording of "[the most recently successfuly loaded module](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:load)". Despite that, the top level module seems to one given as first argument to `:load`.

Comment: If by "\*-form" you mean the module which precedes the prompt (i.e. `A` is the "\*-form" in `*A>`) then you can explicitly add such a module at any point after it's loaded with `:m + *A`; the "most recently loaded module" part refers to the mere convenience of GHCi automatically adding the most recent module to the context after you executed a `:load`. And indeed, it seems that is the first module passed to load which is automatically added to the context, not the most recent loaded one. I think that's a mistake in the docs. Regardless, it isn't relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

When I'm developing and I want to use two or more modules at once in GHCi, here's what I do. Let's say I want to use `Control.Monad` and `Control.Lens`, and my own module which I'm programming with called `Main`:

```
> :m Control.Lens Control.Monad
```

Now both `Control.Lens` and `Control.Monad` are in scope.

Now at this point, it seems I forgot to add `Main`, so I can easily put a `+` which will add modules. This is so handy, I usually **always** use it, I was showing you the above solely so you could see how to import multiple modules at once.

```
> :m + Main
```

Or, what I'd ordinarily do, as I just described:

```
> :m + Main Control.Lens Control.Monad
```

I think `Main` is usually included by default, but you get the picture :)

As to reloading, I use the `:r` command to reload, and yeah, it can suck that bindings are lost, but usually I put them into the code I'm writing in, sometimes temporarily, or I use the readline support of the OS to "go up" through the historical backscroll to find previous definitions.

Happy Haskelling!